# XPath: Count true child nodes with different names?

Tags: xpath, infopath

Is it possible to count the following TRUE nodes (with different names) with XPath in the XML below?

```
<my:templateBase>
  <my:executive>true</my:executive>
  <my:seniorManager>false</my:seniorManager>
  <my:manager>false</my:manager>
  <my:supervisor>false</my:supervisor>
  <my:directReport>false</my:directReport>
</my:templateBase>
```

I can't seem to work out the XPATH, e.g. `count(templateBase/*[?=true()])`.

Comment: Have you tried //my:templateBase/count(*[text()='true'])?

Comment: This will return individual counts for each element name in XPath 2.0 (which InfoPath does not support). In XPath 1.0, functions cannot be called in axis steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find all elements which contain the *text* "true" and count them.

```
count(//my:templateBase/*[text() = 'true'])
```

Make sure to correctly register the **namespace** or use `*` instead of `my` as wildcard namespace, for example

```
count(//*:templateBase/*[text() = 'true'])
```

I do not know Infopath, maybe it also just omits namespaces.

If you also want to search **subnodes** for the text "true", use

```
count(//my:templateBase//*[text() = 'true'])
```

Answer (score -1):

The xpath is

```
count(//my:templateBase/*[. = 'true']
```

Please be aware that you abviously have some namespace `my` in your XML. Maybe you have to make your processor aware of this namespaces. You can also use a wildcard, i.e. `*:templateBase`

Comment: While this returns "1" which is correct for this input, your query will never return anything but "1" for multiple true elements.

Comment: @JensErat You are right, my bad. I just changed this so it works now as expected.